# Using scope operator (::) in function header for return value

Tags: c++, function, struct, scope

I'm a bit new to C++. I am using a double-linked PriorityQueue for an assignment, but it's giving me a weird error.

Basically, I have a function which I want to return a pointer to a struct (Node). Since the struct is defined within the class, I would think I should use the scope operator, so that the function header looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::Node * PriorityQueue<T>::getNode(int index)
```

However I am getting a compilation error for this line, which says:

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*'

What is it that I must do in order to return a pointer to this struct? Am I using the scope operator incorrectly?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the complete code, if helpful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class PriorityQueue{
    public:
        struct Node{
            T data;
            int priority;
            Node * next;
            Node * prev;
        };

    PriorityQueue();
    PriorityQueue & operator=(const PriorityQueue &rhs);
    bool isEmpty();         //Returns true if queue is empty
    int getLength();        //Returns length of queue
    void enqueue(T data, int p);    //Enqueues data T with priority p
    void enqueue(T data);           //Enqueues data T with priority 1
    T dequeue();                    //Dequeues and returns data at head of queue
    void clearQueue();              //Empties queue
    T peek();                       //Returns data at head of queue without dequeing it
    T peekAt(int n);                //Returns data element n without dequeuing it
    int getPriority(int n);         //Returns priority of item at position n
    void display();                 //Prints list of data elements to screen
    void revDisplay();
  //  void swap(Node * n1, Node *n2);
    void swapUp(Node * target);     //Swaps target node with it's neighbor next in line
    bool contains(T data);          //Returns true if data exists as an element anywhere on the queue
    ~PriorityQueue();

    private:
        int size;
        Node * head, *tail;

        int getPos(Node * thisNode);
        Node * getNode(int index);
};

template <typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue(){
    size = 0;
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}

template <typename T>
PriorityQueue<T> & PriorityQueue<T>::operator=(const PriorityQueue &rhs){
    clearQueue();
    for(int n = 0; n < rhs.size(); n++)
        enqueue(rhs.peekAt(n));
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
int PriorityQueue<T>::getLength(){
    return size;
}

template <typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::Node * PriorityQueue<T>::getNode(int index){
    Node * result;
    if(size == 0){
        std::cout << "\nERROR: get node called on empty PriorityQueue\n";
        throw 3;
    } else {
        result = head;
        for(int n = 0; n < index; n++)
            result = result->prev;
    }
    return result;
```

}

Comment: `typename` is missing

Comment: Is it? I have "template <typename T>" right above it, which works for the other functions without an error. And I have <T> right after the class name, as is standard. Could you please tell me what it should look like if not the way I have it?

Comment: I mean `typename` prior to dependent name, `template <typename T> typename PriorityQueue<T>::Node *`

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know you had to do that. Thank you very much!